# Search for a Pattern in a Pandas Column, abstract the value on the left of the pattern

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a column in a Pandas Dataframe like this (dtype = "O"):

```
Column_string 
! 111  PATTERN1   .......,,,,,,.... !444PATTERN2
! 222  PATTERN3   .......,,,,,,.... !555 PATTERN3
! 333  PATTERN4   .......,,,,,,.... !666 PATTERN5
```

I want to **abstract a value on the left side of a pattern, until the '!'.** For example, If I am looking for PATTERN1, the result that I want is: 111.

I want to create new columns, based on a specific pattern. So the desired output (if I am only looking for PATTERN1 and PATTERN2:

```
Column_string                                            PATTERN1  PATTERN2
! 111  PATTERN1   .......,,,,,,.... !444PATTERN2         111       444
! 222  PATTERN3   .......,,,,,,.... !555 PATTERN3        none      none 
! 333  PATTERN4   .......,,,,,,.... !666 PATTERN5        none      none
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [str.findall](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html)

```
##sample df
                                      Column_string 
0   ! 111  PATTERN1   .......,,,,,,.... !444PATTERN2
1  ! 222  PATTERN3   .......,,,,,,.... !555 PATTERN3
2  ! 333  PATTERN4   .......,,,,,,.... !666 PATTERN5
3      3434 PATTERN .................... 435 PATTERN
```

---

```
patterns = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['Column_string '].str.findall('((?<=!)\s*\d+\s*(?=PATTERN))').tolist()).rename({0:'PATTERN1',1:'PATTERN2'},axis=1))
df.join(patterns)
```

---

```
                                      Column_string  PATTERN1 PATTERN2
0   ! 111  PATTERN1   .......,,,,,,.... !444PATTERN2    111       444
1  ! 222  PATTERN3   .......,,,,,,.... !555 PATTERN3    222       555 
2  ! 333  PATTERN4   .......,,,,,,.... !666 PATTERN5    333       666 
3      3434 PATTERN .................... 435 PATTERN    None     None
```

**Note**: If the PATTERN keywords in the string points to some pattern of sort, then below works

```
##extract the number value where pattern1 and pattern2 is present
print(df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['Column_string '].str.findall('((?<=!)\s*\d+\s*(?=PATTERN1|PATTERN2))').tolist()).rename({0:'PATTERN1',1:'PATTERN2'},axis=1)))
```

---

```
                                      Column_string  PATTERN1 PATTERN2
0   ! 111  PATTERN1   .......,,,,,,.... !444PATTERN2    111        444
1  ! 222  PATTERN3   .......,,,,,,.... !555 PATTERN3     None     None
2  ! 333  PATTERN4   .......,,,,,,.... !666 PATTERN5     None     None
3      3434 PATTERN .................... 435 PATTERN     None     None
```

Comment: Thanks! But now I also got the patterns in the columns 'PATTERN1' and 'PATTERN2' for rows where these patterns are not appearing (for example PATTERN3, PATTERN4 and PATTERN5).